# logaritmic function in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} log  (-1+\frac{1}{n}i) = \pi i $$ and $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} log  (-1-\frac{1}{n}i) =- \pi i $$

From $$ log  (z)= log(\mid z \mid) + \theta i  $$

$$ log  (-1+\frac{1}{n}i)= log(1+\frac{1}{n^2}) +arctan(....)i $$

Comment: where's your branch-cut?

Comment: Complex plane without -x axis

Comment: So then, one limit is $\pi i$ and the other is $-\pi i$.

Comment: thank you i understand